# How to calculate value of all rows in one datagrid column

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have this code trying to make it work but it just wont.

```
private void Izračunaj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //it calculates value on click
{
    int total;
    foreach(dataGridView1 column in dataGridView1.Rows()) // 
    {
       total = total + int32.Parse(column[2].ToString()); 
    } 
    textbox text = total; // want to have calculated value displayed in a text box
}
```

Error I get:

> Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.Rows' cannot be used like a method.

I just dont know which syntax i need to use there.

Comment: What is it's datasource? You should use that.

Comment: datasource is datagrid typed in data, or imported from textfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Rows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a property and you are using `()` which designates a method. Just remove the brackets.

```
foreach(dataGridView1 column in dataGridView1.Rows)  //No ()
```

If you want to use LINQ then you can do:

```
total = dataGridView1.Rows
                .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                .Sum(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[2]));
```

You need to access `Cell` property of the row for your calculation.

To show it in the TextBox

```
textBox1.text = total.ToString();
```

Comment: have to have it displayed in a text box? It doesnt show calculated data in text box, i just added after your last line this code: "string texxt = total.ToString();
                                      textBox1.Text = texxt;"

Comment: @mateoZD, I didn't cover that part in my answer assuming that it is not the reason you are getting the error. But now I have edited the question with that detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should solve your problem

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
}
```